# How to call mapping that maps structs from different contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

I would like to ask if it is possible to see struct data from a different contract.

According this post: [copy a struct from Contract A into a struct in Contract B using Contract C](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11016/copy-a-struct-from-contract-a-into-a-struct-in-contract-b-using-contract-c/11020#11020) it is not possible but it is really old so I would like to ask if they didn't change it.

Here is an example:

So you create a mapping in contract 1 like this

```
Contract1 {
    struct Example {
        address example;
        uint exampleUint;
    } 
    mapping(address => Example) public map;
}
```

Then you assign it some value and call it from contract 2

```
Contract2 {
    Contract1 public con; //You assign it address in contructor 
    
    function callMap(address adr) public {
        uint i = con.map(adr) //And here is where I'm stuck
    }
}
```

How do you call the specific variable of the struct?
Normally you can just do it like this:

```
map[msg.sender].example;
```

But from a different contract it doesn't work and I tried almost every method I think.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access an external contract's storage, you need a build a function to return the data:

```
function getMap(address adr) external returns(address, uint) {
    return (map[adr].example, map[adr].exampleUnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access external contract storage from another contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Play {

    mapping (uint256 => bool) public tabs;

    function set() public {
        tabs[1] = true;
    }

}

contract Find {
        Play p;
        
    function callingPlay(address _addr) public {
        p = Play(_addr);
    }

    function read(uint256 u) public view returns(bool) {
        return(p.tabs(1));
    } 
}
```

Also you can access struct of a mapping of another contract

check this answer here: [Accessing a public mapping within a contract from a different contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13616/accessing-a-public-mapping-within-a-contract-from-a-different-contract)